# htaccess redirect url without changing address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, http-status-code-301

Im using bigcartel and i would like to redirect my url to bigcartels url without changing the broswers address bar, i.e
www.example.com to be redirect to www.test.bigcartel.com but show www.example.com in the browsers address bar

I dont want to use iframes but htaccess file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/testing\.bigcartel\.com\/" [L]
```

can anybody help? i found this below but didn't know what to change to make it work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+)$ ?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enable mod_proxy. Then allow access with:

```
<proxy http://www.test.bigcartel.com>
       Allow from all
</proxy>
```

And setup the redirection:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.test.bigcartel.com
```

For more options see the [docs for mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

Comment: how do i enable mod_proxy? do i just paste the above proxy & proxypass into the .htaccess file

Comment: It really depends on your configuration. Probably you can do something like sudo a2enmod proxy

Comment: is there nothing i can do in the htaccess file?? im currently using a iframe